# FDD convergence of subsequences

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

First, sorry for this probably very stupid question. Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of random variables (e.g. in $\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X$ in distribution. Now look at the process $(Y_n(t),t\geq0):=(X_{[nt]},t\geq0)$. Do I have convergence of FDD now, i.e. does
$(Y_n(t_1),\dots,Y_n(t_k))\stackrel{d}{\to}(X,\dots,X)$ for all $t_i\in(0,\infty)$ hold?

I know that marginal convergence holds, since for a fixed $t$, $Y_n(t)$ is just a subsequence of $X_n$. But do we also get FDD convergence? I mean, there do is quite strong dependence between the terms, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $k=2$, $t_1=1$ and $t_2=2$. If $(Y_n(1),Y_n(2))$ converged in distribution to $(X,X)$, then in particular $X_n-X_{2n}$ would converge to $0$ in distribution. But it is not always the case. For example, if $X$ is a symmetric non-degenerated random variable and $X_n=X$ if $n$ is even, $-X$ if $n$ is odd, then taking $n$ odd we would have $2X=0$ in distribution.

Comment: Nice, clear and simple answer. Perfect!